# Copying static list to local temp list

Tags: c#, .net

Hello I have some static lists, and I have lots of websocket connection and uptading these lists. But in paribuMiktarHesaplama() function, I want to use local temp lists to not change my static lists. But when anything changes on local list , its also effecting my static lists. I didnt any assignment, why its changing and How can I fix ?

```
    static List<decimal> p_btcTlAskPrice = new List<decimal>(new decimal[2]);
    static List<decimal> p_btcTlAskQuantity = new List<decimal>(new decimal[2]);
    static List<decimal> b_btcUsdtBidPrice = new List<decimal>(new decimal[20]);
    static List<decimal> b_btcUsdtBidQuantity = new List<decimal>(new decimal[20]);
    /// and more list here...
```

Static lists

```
    public static (decimal,int,decimal,decimal,decimal) FindMin(decimal paribuPrice, decimal paribuAmount, decimal binancePrice,decimal binanceAmount,decimal usdtTryPrice, decimal usdtTryAmount)
    {
        decimal paribuTotal,binanceTotal,usdtTotal;
        decimal enkucuk;
        int enkucukList;
        paribuTotal = paribuPrice* paribuAmount/usdtTryPrice;
        binanceTotal = binancePrice * binanceAmount;
        enkucuk = usdtTryAmount;
        usdtTotal = usdtTryAmount;
        enkucukList = 3;
        if (paribuTotal < enkucuk) { 
            enkucuk = paribuTotal;
            enkucukList = 1;
        }
        if (binanceTotal < enkucuk) {
            enkucuk = binanceTotal;
            enkucukList = 2;
        }

        return (enkucuk, enkucukList,paribuTotal,binanceTotal,usdtTotal);
    }


    public static void paribuMiktarHesaplama(List<decimal> paribuPrice,List<decimal> paribuAmount,List<decimal> binancePrice,List<decimal> binanceAmount)
    {
        var i = 0; var j = 0; var k = 0; decimal enKucuk = 0 ; int enKucukList; decimal totalAmount=0; decimal enKucukParibu = 0; decimal enKucukBinance = 0; decimal enKucukUsdt = 0;
        var tempParibuAmount = paribuAmount; var tempBinanceAmount = binanceAmount; var tempUsdtTryAmount = b_usdtTryBidQuantity;
        var tempParibuPrice = paribuPrice; var tempBinancePrice = binancePrice; var tempUsdtTryPrice = b_usdtTryBidPrice;
        while (true)
        {
            if (tempParibuPrice[i] * paribuFee < tempBinancePrice[j] / binanceFee * tempUsdtTryPrice[k] / binanceFee)
            {//en küçük miktarın çıkarılması lazım
                var returnTuple = FindMin(tempParibuPrice[i], tempParibuAmount[i], tempBinancePrice[j], tempBinanceAmount[j], tempUsdtTryPrice[k], tempUsdtTryAmount[k]);
                enKucuk = returnTuple.Item1;
                enKucukList = returnTuple.Item2;
                enKucukParibu = returnTuple.Item3;
                enKucukBinance = returnTuple.Item4;
                enKucukUsdt = returnTuple.Item5;
                totalAmount += enKucuk; // dolar cinsinden
                if (enKucukList == 1)
                {
                    //paribu
                    tempBinanceAmount[j] = (enKucukBinance - enKucuk)/binancePrice[j];
                    tempUsdtTryAmount[k] = (enKucukUsdt - enKucuk);
                    tempParibuAmount.RemoveAt(0);
                    tempParibuPrice.RemoveAt(0);
                    //i++;
                }
                else if (enKucukList == 2)
                {
                    //binance
                    tempParibuAmount[i] = (enKucukParibu - enKucuk ) * b_usdtTryBidPrice[k];
                    tempUsdtTryAmount[k] = (enKucukUsdt - enKucuk);
                    tempBinanceAmount.RemoveAt(0);
                    tempBinancePrice.RemoveAt(0);
                    //j++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //tether
                    tempBinanceAmount[j] = (enKucukBinance - enKucuk) / binancePrice[j];
                    tempParibuAmount[i] = (enKucukParibu - enKucuk) * b_usdtTryBidPrice[k]/paribuPrice[i];
                    tempUsdtTryAmount.RemoveAt(0);
                    tempUsdtTryPrice.RemoveAt(0);
                    //k++;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"alınacak miktar {totalAmount} fiyatlar paribu {paribuPrice[i]} binance {binancePrice[j]} usdt {b_usdtTryBidPrice[k]}");
    }
```

functions

```
        p_btcTlAskPrice[0] = 600;
        p_btcTlAskQuantity[0] = 60;
        b_btcUsdtBidPrice[0] = 100;
        b_btcUsdtBidQuantity[0] = 80;
        b_usdtTryBidPrice[0] = 7;
        b_usdtTryBidQuantity[0] = 500;

        p_btcTlAskPrice[1] = 650;
        p_btcTlAskQuantity[1] = 100;
        b_btcUsdtBidPrice[1] = 95;
        b_btcUsdtBidQuantity[1] = 50;
        b_usdtTryBidPrice[1] = 6.8m;
        b_usdtTryBidQuantity[1] = 10000;
        paribuMiktarHesaplama(p_btcTlAskPrice, p_btcTlAskQuantity, b_btcUsdtBidPrice, b_btcUsdtBidQuantity);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tempParibuAmount = paribuAmount
```

is an assignment that takes the reference of the List you passed. What you need to do is to create a copy of the paribuAmount and store that copy instead:

```
var tempParibuAmount = new List<decimal>(paribuAmount)
```

Do that instead for every temp list you create